# How do you add an html data attribute to the opened image in Fancybox 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I would like the opened image to have the attribute `data-pin="true"`.

Here is what I want the html of the **opened** image to look like:

```
<img data-pin="true" class="fancybox-image" src="/uploads/gallery_item/image/426/full_ExShow2013_3156.jpg#lightbox0" alt="" >
```

Here is the JS I have that isn't working:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    beforeLoad: function(){
      $(this.element).data("pin", "true")
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

HTML of the thumbnail images:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="/uploads/gallery_item/image/426/full_example.jpg" rel="gallery">
          <img alt="" data-src="/uploads/gallery_item/image/426/example.jpg" src="/uploads/gallery_item/image/426/example.jpg" style="width: 301px; height: 301px;"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML please?

Comment: @APAD1 Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather target the selector of the opened image like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeShow: function () {
        $(".fancybox-image").attr("data-pin", true)
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aL7qn/)**

**NOTE** : Bear in mind that when you use `$(this.element)`, you are actually referring to the link that triggered fancybox but not the open element itself.

Answer (score 1):

Just because your `img` doesn't have the XML Attribute doesn't mean it don't have the data.

Usually

```
$(something).data("key", value);
```

will not add the actual `data-key` attribute to your XML elements, but they will be stored in the DOM element itself.

If you want to explicitly add the tag attribute you need to do this via `$.attr`.

```
$(something).attr("data-key", value);
```

Comment: Although your approach is correct, I am still wondering what `XML` has to do with the question